# How to lock a collection for the duration of a LINQ query?

Tags: thread-safety, linq-to-objects

I have a Repository class that holds a potentially large number of items in memory.  I want to be able to query it using LINQ-to-objects; the catch is that the Repository needs to be thread-safe - it needs to lock the internal collection for the duration of the query.  The best syntax I have been able to come up with is demonstrated in the sample code below.

```
class Program
{
    class Repository<T>
    {
        private List<T> _items;

        public Repository(IEnumerable<T> items)
        {
            _items = items.ToList();
        }

        public List<TResult> Query<TResult>(Func<IEnumerable<T>, IEnumerable<TResult>> queryBuilder)
        {
            lock (_items)
            {
                var query = queryBuilder(_items);
                return query.ToList();
            }
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var repo = new Repository<int>(new[] { 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32 });
        var result = repo.Query(r => 
                            from i in r
                            where i > 4
                            orderby i descending
                            select i.ToString());

        foreach (var i in result)
            Console.WriteLine(i);

        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

The above code works and guarantees that the lock is held only for as long as it takes to execute the query. However, ideally I would like to use the more natural LINQ paradigm and expose a property of type IEnumerable{T} or IQueryable{T} from the Repository class, like so:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var repo = new Repository<int>(new[] { 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32 });
        var result = from i in repo.Items
                 where i > 4
                 orderby i descending
                 select i);

        foreach (var i in result)
            Console.WriteLine(i);

        Console.Read();
    }
```

What I can't figure out is how to do this while preserving the locking semantics of the original code.  Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone is interested, the solution I ultimately came up with was to create a scoping construct to control the lock lifetime via a "using" block... the calling code ultimately looked something like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var repo = new Repository<int>(new[] { 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32 });


    using(var queryScope = repo.CreateQueryScope())
    {
        var result = from i in queryScope.Items
             where i > 4
             orderby i descending
             select i;

        foreach (var i in result)
            Console.WriteLine(i);
    }

    Console.Read();
}
```

This solution provides semantics similar to what you would have with a LINQ-to-sql DataContext... The using block provides a clear contract to the caller that the collection on which the query is operating will only be locked for the duration of the query.  While it does not prevent the caller from doing something silly, like enumerating the query outside of the using block, it provides a clear cue to discourage this by the fact that the collection is exposed through the QueryScope, and not on the repository class itself.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an idea:

```
public IEnumerable<T> Items
{
    get 
    {
        lock(_items)
        {
            foreach(T item in _items)
                yield return item;
        }
    }
}
```

Doing something like this can be dangerous, though.  You see, `IEnumerable` does not mean that the set ever gets exhausted.  For instance, what if I call `repo.first()` then the `foreach` never returns and the lock does not get released.  So if I call `repo.first()` again, it locks completely.

I had considered a custom enumerator to do something like this, but you run into the same problem.

I think that your way is probably best.

Comment: Thanks Brian for your solution... I had thought about something similar but abandoned the idea for the reasons you mention.  Ultimately I came up with another solution, added as a separate post on this thread.